# Finding the downhill direction vector when given a plane defined by a normal and a point

Tags: math, trigonometry, vectormath

So, I have a plane defined by a point in space P, and a normal N. I want to find the normal vector that points directly "down hill" on the plane. How would I go about figuring this out?

Answer (score 4):

Ok, so the position of the point in space is not needed. What you need to do is take a cross product of your plane normal vector with whatever vector you define to be 'down'. This gives you a vector perpendicular to both of them, i.e. across the slope with a flat gradient. Then you take the cross product of this new vector with the normal again and it will produce the 'downhill' vector that you want: the vector parallel to the slope with the greatest downward component.

So assuming that the normal and down vectors have unit length and that the * operator here represents the cross product:

`gradient = (normal * down) * normal;`

If your 'down' vector is just `(0, 0, -1)`, and it will be for most applications, you can [simplify this calculation](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=((x%2Cy%2Cz)%20cross%20(0%2C0%2C-1))%20cross%20(x%2Cy%2Cz)) in code by assigning the following values:

```
gradient.X = normal.X * normal.Z;
gradient.Y = normal.Y * normal.Z;
gradient.Z = -(normal.X * normal.X) - (normal.Y * normal.Y);
```

Comment: Note that you will not end up with a unit length vector as your result and will have to normalize it yourself if needs be. It will produce a zero length vector if the plane normal points 'up' (indicating a flat plane with no slope) so you will have to check for this before normalizing.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is the negative gradient vector. The gradient should be the "uphill" tangent vector, so given that it's a plane, if you negate that it should be the "downhill" tangent vector.
So, if

```
PLANE : z = ax + by + c where N = <a,b,c>
grad(z) = <d/dx(ax + by + c),d/dy(ax + by + c)> = <a,b>
-grad(z) = <-a,-b>
```

<s>Therefore, the "downhill" tangent *should* be <-a,-b>.</s>

Solving for the rate of descent is left as an exercise to the reader :D

*Note that the position P doesn't matter for determining the gradient.*

Edit: Actually, I think I have to contradict myself. I'm thinking that if you look "down" onto a plane with the normal vector pointing "up" (like a flagpole sticking straight out of a ski slope) then the "downhill" tangent vector would actually be the projection of N onto the XY plane, thus t = . I'm not quite sure why the gradient thing didn't work out though.
Of course, this would imply that, if c < 0, down is up ;)